# PowerShell: Export-csv writing properties in long array

Tags: arrays, powershell, properties

Following is an example of my code:

---

```
$logpath = @(gci -path "c:\logs")
foreach ($i in $logpath)    
        {
        [array]$n += ($i.tostring()).trimend(".log")
    [array]$t += ($i.tostring()).lastwritetime
    }
$obj = new-object psobject
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Logname -Value $n
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name LastWriteTime -Value $t
$i | export-csv c:\temp\logs.csv
```

---

Following is what the output looks like:

```
Name,LastWriteTime  
----,-------------
Value1...,Value1
```

---

Following is what I want it to look like:

```
Name,LastWriteTime  
Value1,Value1
Value2,Value2
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to use your code can you try this :

```
$logpath = @(gci -path "c:\logs")
$objects = @() # Empty array
foreach ($i in $logpath)    
{
  $n = ($i.tostring()).trimend(".log")
  $t = ($i.tostring()).lastwritetime

  $obj = new-object psobject
  $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Logname -Value $n
  $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name LastWriteTime -Value $t
  $objects += $obj
}

$objects | export-csv c:\temp\logs.csv
```

I just use an array of objects inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

There's a basename property you can use in lieu of trimming off the file extensions:

```
gci -path "c:\logs" |
select @{l='Name';e={$_.basename}},Lastwritetime |
export-csv c:\temp\logs.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying too hard. Simply use a pipeline, `select` the desired properties, then export the result to a CSV:

```
$logFolders = 'C:\logs', 'D:\more\logs', 'H:\some\other\logs'
gci -Path $logFolders `
  | select @{n='Logname';e={$_.Name.TrimEnd(".log")}}, LastWriteTime `
  | Export-Csv 'C:\temp\logs.csv'
```

Comment: Excellent suggestion. However, I am collecting atleast three different kinds of log files from three different locations and I need to put all of them in the same csv. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @user2905175 `Get-ChildItem` takes an array with paths. See updated answer.